# Maven 2 plugin, build + surefire

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, surefire

If i define a plugin in the <build> tag and want to use this in my site command how do i do that? Do i have to define the plugin within <reporting> tag again?

And how about the configuration which i probably have done within the build tag and want to take place at the reporting tag as well? (i dont want to specifie for example a location of a configuration file twice just to use a plugin in 2 lifecycles)

As example: I define my checkstyle plugin in the build tag and configrue a custom location for the rules to be used. I do that because the rules are packed in a jar so i can define it as dependency. This would not be possible if i do it in the reporting tag. But i need to use this plugin in the reporting tag aswell so surfire can generate a report for checkstyle. So i have to define the plugin within the reporting tag aswell.

Maybe i'm doing something complete wrong here but i don't see how i can do it other then that. What i dont like is that i have 1 plugin twice in my pom (in the build tag and reporting tag).

I hope somebody can verify my solution is ok, or give me an advise how to do it better.

thx

kuku

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maven plugin is typically bound to execution in a given lifecycle phase when you define it. The plugin itself specifies which lifecycle phase this is, but you can change this if you have special needs.

If you have a multi-module build you can define a set of plugins with all parameters required in a common parent-pom. This will normally be executed for every sub-module in the build. If you do not want this to happen you can define it (in the parent pom) like this:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
       </configuration>
   ... More plugin cofniguration stuff ...
 </plugin>
```

If you in one or more nested moudules want to enable this plugin you can just say:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
            <skip>false</skip>
       </configuration>
   ... Maybe Configuration ....
 </plugin>
```

In that specific module. You can choose if you want to reconfigure the default parameters which are inherited from the parent definition or not.

I think this is what you're looking for ?

Comment: oh i didn't know about that. So basicly i dont need to add checkstyle and pmd plugin into the reporting tag of the pom because they most likly are bounded to site lifecycle right ?

Comment: If they are declared in the super pom, then yes. You may want to verify that this works as you think ;)

Comment: Should i define them under build - plugins - plugin or build - pluginmanagement - plugins - plugin ? I will try it thx.

Comment: We generally set up the artifactid/groupid/version under plugin -management

Answer (score 2):

In addition to KRosenvold's answer, you can also minimize configuration by declaring a plugin in the `<pluginManagment>` section, perhaps at your [topmost pom in the inheritance chain](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance), and then you can [omit specifying the version of the plugin in all the other places you are declaring it's use](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management).

Parent Pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
<pluginManagement>
```

Child Pom:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```